# Setting a default option using CMB2 select field type

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I am using [CMB2's select](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2#field-types) to pull in a list of posts that a user can choose from in a custom meta box.

I have added a "blank" option to the options array, but I can't figure out how to make that the default option (ie. `<option selected="selected" value="">I'm blank</option>`).

I need to do this so I can use an if statement that says if the field is blank, don't show the output box on the site.  Right now, even if the user hasn't specifically chosen an option, an option with a value is passed through.

Here's the meta box code:

```
$link_post_types = array('charter', 'page');

$meta_boxes['ms_metabox'] = array(
    'id'            => 'ms_metabox',
    'title'         => __( 'Page Links', 'cmb2' ),
    'object_types'  => array( 'page' ), 
    'context'       => 'normal',
    'priority'      => 'high',
    'show_names'    => true, 
    'fields'        => array(  
        array(
            'name'    => __( 'Page Link', 'cmb2' ),
            'desc'    => __( 'Choose the page this will link to', 'cmb2' ),
            'id'      => $prefix . 'page_link',
            'type'    => 'select',
            'options' => ms_get_posttype_options($link_post_types),
        ),

    ),
);


function ms_get_posttype_options($argument) {


 $get_post_args = array(
        'post_type' => $argument,
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby' => 'type',
        'order' => ASC
    );

    $options = array();
    foreach ( get_posts( $get_post_args ) as $post ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID);
        $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );
        $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID);

        $options[] = array(
            'name'  => $title . ' : ' . $post_type,
            'value' => $permalink,
        );
    }
    $empty_option[] = array(
        'name' => 'Please select an option',
        'value' => '',
    );
    $options = array_merge($empty_option, $options);


    return $options;
}
```

There is a `default` argument but when I tried to apply it as in the example, it didn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I halfway figured it out.  The posts I was having problems with were old ones where I had already been messing with the values before I added the blank option - when I created new posts, the default option was the blank one (since it was the first array in the merge).

If anyone has a more foolproof solution I'd like to hear it though!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to the meta box fields array:

```
show_option_none' => true
```